# Basic use of UIAlertView causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, crash, uialertview, exc-bad-access

I'm implementing a very simple iOS application just to practice showing a pop up alert in, and I get an error when I press the alert button:

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x676f6f57)

This is the code:

```
- (IBAction)AlertButton {


    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
         initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Alert"
         delegate:self
         cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
         otherButtonTitles:@"Apple", "Google" ,nil];
    [alert show];}


-(void)alertView :(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButttonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if(buttonIndex == 1){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"]];
    }
    if(buttonIndex == 2){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
    }}
```

Comment: Please don't post a link to your entire project. If you can't describe your problem succintly enough to fit in into the post body here, then your question isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I believe the problem is the name of your button = AlertButton and the name of the IBaction is also AlertButton. There is nothing wrong with the UIAlertView in above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is with the constructor of the `UIAlertView`, in the line:

```
otherButtonTitles:@"Apple", "Google" ,nil];
```

your forget the `@` before `"Google"`. And finally change:

```
-(void)alertView :(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButttonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
```

by

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
```

Comment: "Furthermore, you has to declare the adoption of the protocol UIAlertViewDelegate on your class" - no, you don't have to, it's just a hint for the compiler.

Comment: Yes, you're right, in that case is not necessary, I fix the answer

Comment: Thanks. (Not that I'm advocating avoiding it, because it's good practice to do so, just for the record - people often forget that Objective-C is a highly dynamic language where declarations matter the less.)

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is you miss an `@` in front of `"Google"`, so it is not an `NSString` and hence the crash.

use this
.h

no need for IBOutlet.just

```
 UIAlertView *alert;
```

.m

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"Alert"
              message:@"Alert"
             delegate:self
    cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
    otherButtonTitles:@"Apple", @"Google", nil
];
```